# GaxiosError: Login Required

Tags: node.js, google-api, upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube using Node.js, but I keep encountering a "Login Required" error consistently. I have confirmed that I have the access token correctly as I can log it in my console. Below is the complete code for performing the upload operation. The code includes the necessary context for understanding the issue.

```js
exports.acceptSubmit = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const notificationId = req.params.notificationId;

        // Find the notification by ID
        const notification = await Notification.findById(notificationId);

        if (!notification) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Notification not found." });
        }

        // Get the creator's user ID from the notification
        const creatorId = notification.creatorId;

        // Find the creator based on creatorId
        const creator = await User.findById(creatorId);

        if (!creator) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Creator not found." });
        }

        // Get the creator's access token
        console.log(creator);
        const accessToken = creator.accessToken;

        const pendingVideo = await PendingVideo.findById(notification.videoId);

        if (!pendingVideo) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Pending video not found." });
        }

        const videoTitle = pendingVideo.title;
        const videoDescription = pendingVideo.description;
        const videoUrl = pendingVideo.videoUrl; // Assuming this is the S3 URL
        const thumbnailUrl = pendingVideo.thumbnailUrl; // Assuming this is the S3 URL for thumbnail

        // authenticate with the YouTube Data API using the creator's access token
        const youtube = google.youtube({
            version: 'v3',
            auth: accessToken,
        });

        const videoResponse = await youtube.videos.insert({
            part: 'snippet,status',
            requestBody: {
                snippet: {
                    title: videoTitle,
                    description: videoDescription,
                },
                status: {
                    privacyStatus: 'public', // or 'private' or 'unlisted'
                },
            },
            media: {
                mimeType: 'video/*',
                body: s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: 'editingfiles',
                    Key: 'videos/1693044658221-Course_selling_done.mp4',
                }).createReadStream(),
            },
        });

        // get the uploaded video's ID
        const videoId = videoResponse.data.id;

        // upload the thumbnail
        const thumbnailResponse = await youtube.thumbnails.set({
            videoId: videoId,
            media: {
                mimeType: 'image/jpeg', // or 'image/png'
                body: s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: 'editingfiles',
                    Key: 'thumbnails/1693044658221-server code.png',
                }).createReadStream(),
            },
        });

        return res.json("all good");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error." });
    }
};

I have attempted to regenerate the token, but I continue to receive the same error. I am expecting the code to successfully upload the video to YouTube using the provided access token.

Error
GaxiosError: Login Required.

Any insights into why I might be encountering the "Login Required" error would be greatly appreciated.
```